# State machines in MDriven

Tags: uml, modeling, mdriven

I am just wondering if anyone of you know were you can find the "UML state machines" in MDriven? I just started working with this modeling tool and need to add some different allowed states for the classes in my model but I can not seem to find it anywhere.

I looked it up on http://www.mdriven.net/ as well as https://www.capableobjects.com/ 
and obviously it is available in the program but I couldn't find any information on *where*?

Maybe I am just blind. I am starting out with the "starter version" of MDriven so perhaps that's why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you right-click on a class, then you have "Add State machine".
What you will get is a new Attribute called State that is marked as "Is State attribute". You can rename the attribute and have multiple state machines per class. Each state attribute has a state diagram associated.